# Cookies counter php

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to do this counter for cookies. The cookies give the right values when I visit the site more than once but for first visit, it always tell me that the cookies(both) are not set. I'm new at PHP so I'm not sure if I missed something. The cookies are set before html tags.

```
setcookie("user", isset($_COOKIE["user"])? ++$_COOKIE["user"] : 1);
setcookie("date", date("d/m/y h:i:s"));
$count = $_COOKIE["user"];

---------------------------------
<body>

    <p><?php
        if( $count == 1)
            echo "Welcome! You're new here.";
        else
            echo "Hello, you have visited " .$_COOKIE["user"]. " times.";
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "Your last visit was ".$_COOKIE["date"];

    ?></p>

</body>
```

Comment: When you access the page for the second time (so the cookie is defined) does it print: Hello, you have visited 1 times. ?

Comment: No it prints "you have visited 2 times" and the count increases by 1 after every refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setcookie` function puts the cookie into the servers http header, which is sent along with the first request. The `$_COOKIE` array however does not get these values passed internally (from the setcookie function), instead it is generated from the request headers sent by the browser and this only happens after the browser got the cookie (from the first request) and sends it back on the second request.

What you could do is this:

```
$count = isset($_COOKIE["user"])?$_COOKIE["user"]:1;
```

Comment: Thanks your comment made it clear for me but your idea didn't solve it 100%. But I did figure it out in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but all I see for now is that else is used the false way.
You can write:

```
if (cond)
    do();
else
    doelse();
```

Just single lines work like this.
Use instead:

```
<?php
        if($count == 1)
            echo "Welcome! You're new here.";
        else {
            echo "Hello, you have visited " .$_COOKIE["user"]. " times.";
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "Your last visit was ".$_COOKIE["date"];
        }
?>
```